Docker compose for apisix, etcd, apisix-dashbaord
I am trying to create a simple docker-compose setup for apisix, apisix-dashboard and etcd. It's purpose is just to spin up a simple setup for playing around and testing locally.
Unfortunately, the apisix examples in the apisix-docker Github repo are not working and the docs are incomplete.
So far, I managed to spin up the three containers, but when I try to login to apisix-dashboard, I get an error "Request Error Code: 10000 username or password error", but there is no corresponding log message. What is going wrong?
This is my compose.yaml:
services:
  # etcd for APISIX configuration storage
  etcd:
    image: bitnami/etcd:3.5.17
    container_name: etcd
    environment:
      ALLOW_NONE_AUTHENTICATION: yes
      ETCD_ADVERTISE_CLIENT_URLS: http://etcd:2379
      ETCD_LISTEN_CLIENT_URLS: http://0.0.0.0:2379
    ports:
      - "2379:2379"

  # APISIX instance
  apisix:
    image: apache/apisix:3.11.0-debian
    container_name: apisix
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - etcd
    volumes:
      - ./apisix_conf/config.yaml:/usr/local/apisix/conf/config.yaml:ro
    ports:
      - "9080:9080"
      - "9443:9443"
      # - "9091:9091" # APISIX Admin API port (default is 9091)

  # APISIX Dashboard
  apisix-dashboard:
    image: apache/apisix-dashboard:3.0.1-alpine
    container_name: apisix-dashboard
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - apisix
      - etcd
    volumes:
      - ./dashboard_conf/conf.yaml:/usr/local/apisix-dashboard/conf/conf.yaml:ro
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"

apisix_conf/config.yaml:
apisix:
  node_listen: 9080          # APISIX listening port for HTTP
  
deployment:
  admin:
    allow_admin:
      - 0.0.0.0/0
    admin_key:
      - name: "admin"
        key: edd1c9f034335f136f87ad84b625c8f1
        role: admin
  etcd:
    host:
      - http://etcd:2379
    prefix: "/apisix"
    timeout: 30

dashboard_conf/conf.yaml:
conf:
  listen:
    port: 9000

  etcd:
    endpoints:
      - etcd:2379
      
authentication:
  secret: secret
  users:
    - username: admin
    - password: admin


The error is in the file dashboard_conf/conf.yaml, specifically in this snippet:
  users:
    - username: admin
    - password: admin

Appearently, this results in an empty list of users (see the configuration parser apache/apisix-dashboard/api/internal/conf/conf.go, specifically lines L129-L132 and L300-L311), because you're defining 2 wrong users: one without the password field, and the other without the username field.
That's why you are not be able to log in.
It should instead be:
  users:
    - username: admin
      password: admin

